# How to deal with inheritance in PageObjects pattern of WebDriver?

Tags: java, inheritance, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

Could please anybody suggest a way to deal with Inheritance regarding Page Objects pattern ?

For instance, page objects need to share properties and methods.

```
public class LoginPage extends SuperPage
public class SuperPage extends LoadableComponent<SuperPage>
```

This would be Ok. But the problem is that your UnitTests don't extend SuperPage, they extend TestCase, that holds global properties etc. for Tests.

I try to avoid duplication, because I need to share the same stuff in TestCase and SuperPage... Pages and Tests can extend only one of these.

For instance, I need the same Form Data in  PageObjects and Tests available...

Example:

If you have a PageObject for filling out a html form, you need names of the form fields, but you need them even in other pageObjects. So that you extend SuperPage where the field names are. They cannot be supplied from UnitTests, because of this for instance :

```
@CacheLookup
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = namespace + signifLvl)
private WebElement sigLvl;
@CacheLookup
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = namespace + languageTo)
private WebElement langTo;  
@CacheLookup
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = namespace + languageFrom)
private WebElement langFrom;
@CacheLookup
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = namespace + description)
private WebElement desc;
```

But on the other hand, you need to use these in UnitTest methods, because you supply different values from them to PageObjects.

Otherwise it would always by like this, prepopulating PageObjects with variables from TestCase :

```
@Test
public void doStuff() throws IOException {
    driver.navigate().refresh();
    FillOutFormPage fofp = new FillOutFormPage(driver);
    fofp.fill(some values from TestCase);
    fofp.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done much with WebDriver, but I remember, that most of of the PageObjects I created and tested, didn't need to be populated. They just contained a scenario - sequence of conditions to be tested, in form of testing methods to be called from UnitTest. The only property to be shared between PageObjects were just a few fields or field names (very exceptionally - like a submit button that when clicked, validation is triggered - it needs to be reachable from all components that forms the entire page and validate something) and namespace for instance.

In case of creating PageObjects that need to be populated with varying data. It must go from outside (UnitTests). So I guess one should be populating or rather constructing pageObjects with data in unitTests, but only if it is a "service like component" that is needed by others and must be in different that initial state. If you always do it like this, there shouldn't be a need for sharing this kind of data between TestCase and PageObjects.

There should be a "boarder" between PageObjects and UnitTests ...varying data must come from unitTests into pageObjects testing methods, static data regarding html stay in PageObjects... IMHO

I don't recommend having SuperPageObejct because as you have it. SomePageObject.get() method returns SuperObject instead of SomePageObject... What you need in object1, stays in object one. There should be no inheritance. In Object1 there is nothing that you should need from object2.

Answer (score 0):

One of the key aspects of the Page Object pattern is the isolation of test cases and page structure.  If your tests are typing into fields, you're probably Doing It Wrong.  Instead of having tests fill in the pages' variables, your pages should provide methods that allow tests to perform important actions.  Thus instead of:

`myPage.sigLvl = "10";
myPage.langTo = "en";
myPage.langFrom = "de";`

you do:

`myPage.addTranslation("en", "de", 10);`

The point is that your test shouldn't care about the structure of the page (what the fields are called, how they're arranged on the page, *etc.*), but rather about the behavior of the application.

Comment: In my case the html form has 12 fields so I'm creating a Map<fieldName, value> ...because having methods with 12 fields is a nightmare to maintain ... If I have 5 methods on the FormPageObjects that test validation etc, passing by 12 values via method arguments is bad idea, you know...that's why I needed the field names to get them via reflection then in FormObject

Comment: I really can't get used to this pattern http://stackoverflow.com/q/6250485/306488